# Heroku creates dozen of sh and ruby process

Tags: heroku

I've successfully installed Heroku Toolbelt on Mac, everything is working well except that Heroku creates multiply sh and ruby processes which freezes my mac on each usage of `heroku` app in Terminal.

Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve issues we need to first remove Heroku Tollbelt:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku
```

and install Heroku using [brew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install heroku
```

There is slight possibility that you'll have to install additional gems in order to fully use Heroku, you'll be notified in command line if there's such need.

**EDIT**

Issue was resolved in newer version.